# Can someone clarify how many metrics exist that satisfy the EFEs?

Tags: general-relativity

As I currently understand it, there are two ways to work with the Einstein Field Equations: (1) exact solutions and (2) approximations that work under certain conditions.

I also understand that there are two basic ways to go about discovering exact solutions.

1. Propose a matter distribution and see if there exists a metric out there in nature that matches the results you get around such matter distributions.
2. Propose a metric and see if there is a matter distribution that matches it.

**My Question:**

In Newtonian gravity, we basically only had one formula, Newton's gravity equation. But it seems like for Einstein gravity we have to do everything on a case by case basis, so we actually end up with many different tools that are useful but not universally applicable to all circumstances. Is that a misimpression? If not, how many different kinds of metrics do we expect are needed to describe the most common gravitational phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an infinite number of solutions. Given one solution, we may always perturb it to get a new solution.

See Wald (1984) sections 7.4, 7.5 and references therein.

Note that the perturbed solutions may not be physically significant. In particular, asymptotic flatness is not always preserved.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. I will get Wald and read about that.

Comment: @StanShunpike: It should be noted that Wald only discusses vacuum solutions ($R_{ab}=0$) that possess a Killing vector. For the vacuum equations, we can *generate* new solutions to the field equations. For the full equations $R_{ab}=8\pi T_{ab}$ there could be an infinity of solutions, but we would have to come up with an infinity of $T_{ab}$s.

Comment: @StanShunpike: A note about Wald. Wald is a book that you read once you know GR to get in mathematical rigor and advanced topics. Most importantly, you are expected to know some topology. The first chapter of Lee should give you (more than) enough, though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It makes sense. Everyone who has suggested it on SE has been very math adept.